# Azure VM CNAME Returns HTTP 502

Tags: virtual-machines, azure, cname-record

I have a Virtual Machine in Azure with a Cloud Service VIP.  I have opened up an HTTPS endpoint.  If I alter my hosts file to point to the VIP, I can reach my IIS site without any trouble.  So far so good.

I created a CNAME record in my registrar:

subdomain.mydomain.com --> vm-west-us.cloudapp.net

Unfortunately, I cannot reach the IIS server on the VM using this CNAME DNS record.  I get back a 502 error (using Fiddler).  I know that the CNAME record has propagated b/c I can ping it and it resolves the domain name / IP.

I suspect that if I add an A record in the registrar pointing directly to the VIP, this will resolve the problem.  But what am I doing wrong with the CNAME record?

**Screenshot of VM dash:**

[image: screenshot of vm dash]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dumb mistake. The Azure setup and the CNAME approach were both fine.  I mistakenly mapped the wrong subdomain at the domain registrar.